# Guice Provider Interception

Tags: java, guice, interceptor

I need to access to an instance provided via Guice @Provides, so i'm testing a way to access the @Provides Method via a Interceptor...but no way, the interceptor never distpaches.
Also i can't change Provider Method Signature , cause inherits from  another class  ....

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule{

    public static class MyInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor{
        @Override
        public Object invoke(final MethodInvocation methodInvocation) throws Throwable {    
            System.out.println("MyModule ::: Intercepted@invoke! : "+ methodInvocation.getMethod().getName());  
            return methodInvocation.proceed();
        }       
    }

    @Provides
    StampInterface getStamp(){
        StampExampleImpl se = new StampExampleImpl();
        se.setId("theID");
        se.setTst(System.currentTimeMillis());  
        return se;      
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure() {

       bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(),
                       Matchers.annotatedWith(Provides.class),  
                       new MyInterceptor());   

    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        StampInterface s = Guice.createInjector(new MyModule()).getInstance(StampInterface.class);  
        System.out.println( s.getTst());        
        System.out.println("---------------------------");      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Please check the limitations of guice aop as described here: https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AOP#limitations

> Instances must be created by Guice by an @Inject-annotated or no-argument constructor It is not possible to use method interception on instances that aren't constructed by Guice.

You are creating the StampExampleImpl yourself via "new" (doesn't matter that you do so inside a produces method). Thus guice does not know about it in regard to interception.

Quick fix: let guice create the impl instance for you:

```
@Provides
StampInterface getStamp(StampExampleImpl se){
    se.setId("theID");
    se.setTst(System.currentTimeMillis());  
    return se;      
}
```

2nd Problem: why matching on "annotatedWith(Provides)"? You want to intercept the getTsd() method of your StampInterface, and that is not annotated. The annotation is on the producer method of your module, which is a different thing.

Comment: I just need to update a "provided object"  when this is expired.  In a sigleton scope , using a a @Provides i get an object...that always is the same (pure logic! )....I can't use RequestScope  ....so i was trying to update that object via a trick..like intercepting...but i think there is no way. I know maybe there is model/arquitecture issue...but i can't change the model (( so  i'm trying to find any trick to change it . Difficult (( . Thank u very much

Comment: Does that mean this question is answered? Or do you need additional info? Maybe it would be a good idea to ask a new question describing the problem you want to solve instead of asking about details of one possible solution.

Comment: It asks.... but the good way is to change the model. It has no sense this. Thank u.